# How do I create a vector with a user defined size?

Tags: c++, vector

I want to create a program that prompts the user for the size of the vector, then applies that size to the vector (filled with random numbers). This is what I have so far, but I am at a loss. There was a similar question on this site but it was closed due to being too ambiguous. How can I create x number of data.push_back instances based on a number entered by the user?

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    data.push_back(rand()%10+1);

    for (int i=0; i<data.size(); i++)
    {
        cout<<"Vector: "<<i<<" "<<data[i]<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following if you have to use push_back

```
main()
{
int n;
cin >> n;
vector<int> data;   
srand(time(NULL));

for (int i = 0 ; i < n; i++)
{
        data.push_back(rand()%10+1);
}
for (int i=0; i<data.size(); i++)
{
cout<<"Vector: "<<i<<" "<<data[i]<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

You may also pre-allocate the whole vector, which is more efficient.

```
main()
{
int n;
cin >> n;
vector<int> data(n);    
srand(time(NULL));

for (int i = 0 ; i < n; i++)
{
    data[i] = rand()%10 + 1;
}
for (int i=0; i<data.size(); i++)
{
cout<<"Vector: "<<i<<" "<<data[i]<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @sandy!! That cleared up a lot, yet uncovers more questions....

What does the 2nd "for" loop do? I get the first "for" loop (and I'm kicking myself for not thinking of doing "i < n"), but to me the second one reads that it will only display the vector values if the index is less than the vector size??

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

1. Get a number from the user using `std::cin` and store it in an `int` or preferably `std::vector<int>::size_type`. Let's call this number `n`.
2. Loop `n` times, each time calling `rand()`, and `push_back` the result into your `std::vector<int>`

Note that `std::vector<int>` is a dynamic container and it's size can change at runtime. In your case, you do not have to specify it's size at compile time.

Comment: What loop should I use to loop n times?

Comment: @cowlicker12 You're free to choose whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

You could go for:`

```
srand(time(NULL));
std::vector<int> data;
int x;
std::cin>>x;
data.resize(x);
std::generate(data.begin(), data.end(), [](){return rand()%10+1;});

for(auto& num : data)
   std::cout<<num<<std::endl;`
```

or, if you want to display the index as well:

```
for (int i=0; i<data.size(); i++)
    cout<<"Vector: "<<i<<" "<<data[i]<<endl;
```

making sure you include the appropriate headers (`<cstdlib>`, `<vector>` and `<algorithm>`)